# I want to do function at open Chrome with web site Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new at Javascript and I have a question.

I want to at start if I open Chrome and web site to do my function.

I want to every time do this function if I open Google Chrome!

I have adblock, and I want if every time I open this web site how2play.pl I want to delete this window scr.hu/0qbal/i9wa2 with code scr.hu/0qbal/gs9sy like in console paste `document.getElementById('sdf09-8e9daf9e854f26f98cabf235ad8343cb').style.display = "none";`

Please explain step by step.

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly, what do you want to achieve on this? It's recommended to learn about JS first, there are several tutorials on the internet :-)

Comment: @C0dekid, I have adblock, and i want if everytime I open this webside http://how2play.pl/ I want to delete this window http://scr.hu/0qbal/i9wa2
with code http://scr.hu/0qbal/gs9sy 
like in console paste document.getElementById('sdf09-8e9daf9e854f26f98cabf235ad8343cb').style.display = "none";

Comment: There is a addon for adblocker called "Element Hiding Helper". Take a look at this: https://adblockplus.org/en/elemhidehelper. Other wise you can write your "own" blocker that scans the page for the "adblock-overlay".

Comment: @C0dekid, thanks it works. But how i can do something like adblock what do in webside: document.getElementById('sdf09-8e9daf9e854f26f98cabf235ad8343cb').style.display
?

Comment: What are you using? Google Chrome or firefox?

Comment: @C0dekid I using Google chrome.

Comment: You need some extension which allows you to run userscripts. E.g. greasemonkey or tampermonkey.

Comment: @Oriol Thx man i loking that! Its awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>                  
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() 
            {
                alertme('this works');
            };


            function alertme(text)
            {
                alert(text);
            }
        </script>

        <button onclick="alertme('you clicked me');">Click Me</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

When the page is done loading or if you click on the button, the code will run a javascript function that will display an alert box.

How it works

In the javascript there is a window.onload = function() -- which allows you to run any function you want immediately when the page is done loading (in this example it will run the alertme('this works');)

When you look at the button you will see that the button contains alertme('you clicked me');

That is also a function that executes when the button is clicked.

Comment: Glad you learned OP some javascript, but unfortunately this isn't what he want to achieve. He isn't specific enough in his question but, he wanted something with adblocker.